# something like plt.matshow but with triangles

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basically, I'd like to make something like the following (triangles not squares as is typically used with plt.matshow). 
[image]

One could start with four 2D arrays, each representing the values for the colours of a set of triangles: right, left, bottom, top:

```
import numpy as np
right=np.random.randn(8, 8)
left=np.random.randn(8, 8)
bottom=np.random.randn(8, 8)
top=np.random.randn(8, 8)
```

But I have no idea about the plotting...

Comment: You're looking for plt.triplot, I think: https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.triplot. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512046/how-to-create-ternary-contour-plot-in-python for a more worked out example that's kinda similar to your plot.

Comment: You may also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291155/plotting-two-distance-matrices-together-on-same-plot), which plots 2 triangles per pixel, but could easily be extended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may indeed use `tripcolor` to plot a set of triangles. In the code below the function `quatromatrix` takes 4 2D arrays of values to colormap as input, creates the triangles and rearanges the colors to fit to the respective positions. It is thus very similar to plotting 4 imshow plots.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def quatromatrix(left, bottom, right, top, ax=None, triplotkw={},tripcolorkw={}):
    if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
    n = left.shape[0]; m=left.shape[1]

    a = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[.5,.5],[1,0],[1,1]])
    tr = np.array([[0,1,2], [0,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,4]])

    A = np.zeros((n*m*5,2))
    Tr = np.zeros((n*m*4,3))

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            k = i*m+j
            A[k*5:(k+1)*5,:] = np.c_[a[:,0]+j, a[:,1]+i]
            Tr[k*4:(k+1)*4,:] = tr + k*5

    C = np.c_[ left.flatten(), bottom.flatten(), 
              right.flatten(), top.flatten()   ].flatten()

    triplot = ax.triplot(A[:,0], A[:,1], Tr, **triplotkw)
    tripcolor = ax.tripcolor(A[:,0], A[:,1], Tr, facecolors=C, **tripcolorkw)
    return tripcolor


right=np.random.randn(8, 8)
left=np.random.randn(8, 8)
bottom=np.random.randn(8, 8)
top=np.random.randn(8, 8)

fig, ax=plt.subplots()

quatromatrix(left, bottom, right, top, ax=ax,
             triplotkw={"color":"k", "lw":1},
             tripcolorkw={"cmap": "plasma"}) 

ax.margins(0)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
```

Answer (score 0):

See the example `matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor(*args, **kwargs)` in the matplotlib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).
Here is a simplyfied version of want you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xy = np.asarray([
    [-0.01, 0.872], [-0.080, 0.883], [-0.069, 0.888], [-0.054, 0.890]])

x = xy[:, 0]*180/3.14159
y = xy[:, 1]*180/3.14159

triangles = np.asarray([[3, 2,  0]  , [3,  1, 2],   [ 0, 2,  1] , 
                        [0,  1, 2]])

xmid = x[triangles].mean(axis=1)
ymid = y[triangles].mean(axis=1)
x0 = -5
y0 = 52
zfaces = np.exp(-0.01*((xmid - x0)*(xmid - x0) + 
                (ymid - y0)*(ymid - y0)))


plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.tripcolor(x, y, triangles, facecolors=zfaces, edgecolors='k')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('tripcolor of user-specified triangulation')
plt.xlabel('Longitude (degrees)')
plt.ylabel('Latitude (degrees)')

plt.show()
```

You should get the following picture:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I used ImportanceOfBeingErnest's code to plot the Q-table for a reinforcement learning project- I wanted to understand it so I went through and made it a bit clearer. Just replace the data (up, down, left, right) with your own.

```
def showQVals(self):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    rows = self.level.NUM_ROWS
    cols = self.level.NUM_COLUMNS

    up = self.q[:,Action.UP].reshape(rows, cols)
    down = self.q[:,Action.DOWN].reshape(rows, cols)
    right = self.q[:,Action.RIGHT].reshape(rows, cols)
    left = self.q[:,Action.LEFT].reshape(rows, cols)

    vertDims = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[.5,.5],[1,0],[1,1]])
    UP = [1,2,4]
    DOWN = [0,2,3]
    RIGHT = [2,3,4]
    LEFT = [0,1,2]
    triDims = np.array([DOWN, UP, RIGHT, LEFT])

    verts = np.zeros((rows*cols*5,2))
    tris = np.zeros((rows*cols*4,3))

    for row in range(rows): #i
        for col in range(cols): #j
            cell = row*cols+col

            #assign slices to the newly constructed verts and tris
            verts[cell*5:(cell+1)*5,:] = np.c_[vertDims[:,0]+col, vertDims[:,1]+row]
            tris[cell*4:(cell+1)*4,:] = triDims + cell*5

    C = np.c_[ up.flatten(), down.flatten(), 
            right.flatten(), left.flatten()   ].flatten()

    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set_title('Q Values')

    triplot = ax.triplot(verts[:,0], verts[:,1], tris)
    tripcolor = ax.tripcolor(verts[:,0], verts[:,1], tris, facecolors=C)

    fig.colorbar(tripcolor)
    plt.show()
```

[q table figure based off of grid map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrsbM.png)