# How to modify number of ticks and apply mutli color gradient in ggtern?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I was experimenting with this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879361/ternary-plot-and-filled-contour) and what I found interesting is that the number of ticks changed when I plotted. In my case I get this:

[image]

The code used is the same as in the OP:

```
#Orignal Data as per Question
a <- c(0.1, 0.5,0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0          , 0         , 0.004166667, 0.45) 
b <- c(0.75,0.5,0  , 0.1, 0.2, 0.951612903,0.918103448, 0.7875     , 0.45)
c <- c(0.15,0  ,0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.048387097,0.081896552, 0.208333333, 0.10) 
d <- c(500,2324.90,2551.44,1244.50, 551.22,-644.20,-377.17,-100, 2493.04) 
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

#For labelling each point.
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

#Build Plot
ggtern(data=df,aes(x=c,y=a,z=b),aes(x,y,z)) + 
  stat_density2d(geom="polygon",
                 n=400,
                 aes(fill=..level..,
                 weight=d,
                 alpha=abs(..level..)),
                 binwidth=100) + 
  geom_density2d(aes(weight=d,color=..level..),
                 n=400,
                 binwidth=100) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=d),color="black",size=5,shape=21) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=id),size=3) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow",high="red") + 
  scale_color_gradient(low="yellow",high="red") + 
  theme_tern_rgbw() + 
  theme(legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(order=1),
         alpha= guide_legend(order=2),
         color="none") + 
  labs(  title= "Ternary Plot and Filled Contour",
         fill = "Value, V",alpha="|V - 0|")

#Save Plot
ggsave("TernFilled.png")
```

I have been trying to increase the number of ticks to 11, but no luck. ***How can the number of ticks be specified?***

**Multi color gradient**

***And is it possible to multi color gradient instead of two color gradient?*** I tried setting

```
scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow",high="red")
```

to

```
scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", mid = "yellow",  high="red")
```

but there was no change. How can it be done?

Comment: @Nicholas Hamilton suggested you to use `scale_fill_gradient2`. Please note the **2**.

Answer (score 0):

`ggtern 2.0.1`, which was published on CRAN a couple of days ago after completely re-writing the package to be compatible with `ggplot2 2.0.0`. A summary of the new functionality in `ggtern 2.0.X` can be found [here](http://ahref.io/UuED1):

So in regards to the number of ticks, unless they are explicitly specified via the 'breaks' argument in each `scale_X_continuous(...)` [where X = T, L or R], or via `limit_tern(...)`, where the same 'breaks' argument gets passed to all three continuous scales, ggtern will try to make a best guess.

Consider the following set of examples:

```
#Set up a plot
df   = data.frame(x=1,y=1,z=1)
base = ggtern(data=df,aes(x,y,z)) + geom_point()

#1. The default case, best guess.
base 

#2. A reduced scale limit, with best guess.
base + limit_tern(.5,.5,.5)

#3. Manual breaks passed to all three ternary scales
base + limit_tern(breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.05))

#4. Manual breaks passed to all three ternary scales, under limited region
base + limit_tern(.5,.5,.5,breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.05))

#5. Manual breaks passed to a single ternary scale, the other two are done by best guess
base + scale_T_continuous(breaks  = seq(0,1,by=0.05))
```