# Creating a ternary plot from Cartesian coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, ggtern

I am trying something - I want to estimate contributions from sources via a mixing triangle.
[image]

I have all data points in the Cartesian system (2 tracers measured)
Now I need to transform my coordinates into  trilinear coordinates.
I was looking for a pre-existing function for that or another way to compute it on my own.
Can someone help me? Is there something existing already in R?
ggtern needs those trilinear coordinates if I did not misunderstood the manual.

Thanks,
Nadine

Comment: I suggest providing some example data (e.g., the data that contributed to the plot shown). Then show what you've tried using `ggtern`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10879361/1199289